# Skipping unittest with decorator in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x

I'm writing some `unittest` and found a rather curious behavior that nearly burned me.

The following test:

```
import unittest

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    @unittest.skip('Not ready yet')
    def test_A(self):
        self.assertTrue(False)

    @unittest.skip
    def test_B(self):
        self.assertTrue(False)

    def test_C(self):
        self.assertTrue(False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

results in:

```
test_A (__main__.Test) ... skipped 'Not ready yet'
test_B (__main__.Test) ... ok
test_C (__main__.Test) ... FAIL

======================================================================
FAIL: test_C (__main__.Test)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 13, in test_C
    self.assertTrue(False)
AssertionError: False is not true

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.000s
```

Using the decorator `unittest.skip` empty does skip the test but then reports it as passed. Therefore this skipped test could be easily forgotten the next day and stay in the skip state forever. What is the reason behind this skip, but report pass behavior?

In case it matters:

- Python: 3.4.3 | Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit)
- OS: RHEL 6.7

Comment: (1.) If you run in _verbose_ mode (using `-v` switch), the test run says "Skipped". (2.) As you already demonstrated, you can include a helpful message to this effect using a string argument to the decorator.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist. Yes I forgot to mention that this is the verbose output. What I was wondering is, why the test is skipped and marked as passed in this situation. Which is partially answered in `user2357112` answer.

Comment: At down voter. Care to explain why this question is bad or how it could be improved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
@decorator
def f(): ...
```

is equivalent to

```
def f(): ...
f = decorator(f)
```

and

```
@decorator(...)
def f(): ...
```

is equivalent to

```
def f(): ...
f = decorator(...)(f)
```

That means when you forget the skip reason, you get the effects of

```
def test_B(self): ...
test_B = unittest.skip(test_B)
```

The test method is passed as the skip reason, and the returned test decorator is assigned to `test_B`. When `unittest` tries to run `test_B`, the test decorator reports no assertion failures, so `unittest` thinks it's a passing test.

The inequivalence of `@decorator` and `@decorator()` is one of Python's design warts, but there isn't much we can do about it.

Comment: I think that's worth a bug ticket.  There's no reason unittest couldn't be modified to do the obvious thing here, and report the test as skipped with no reason provided.

Comment: @wim: I'd probably make it raise an exception, so we don't have weird compatibility headaches.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can see that this is easier to implement. However would argue that implementing the decorator function differently, a simple if clause should do the trick, would remove a potential pitfall. I was assuming this behavior was deliberately chosen for a reason I can't see yet. BTW, I agree that at this point raising an Exception might be better for compatibility. Heck everything is better than simply silently skip/pass.

Comment: @magu_: I can assure you, it wasn't deliberate. People generally just assume their arguments are the right kind of thing in Python, since duck-typing makes explicit type checks messy. No one made a particular decision not to check whether the skip reason is a function.

Comment: @user2357112. I guess you'r right. Even though we could in this case still go for duck-typing instead of type check. I will accept your answer tomorrow if nothing new comes up.